# Jquery get id of td

Tags: php, jquery, html

html code

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($WltQRslt)){
    echo "
    <tr ><td onload='get()' id ='".$row['SNo']."' ><i class='fa fa-line-chart fa-3x'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{$row['Profit']}</td>
<td class='center'><i class='fa fa-database fa-3x' aria-hidden='true'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{$row['Server']}</td>
<td><i class='fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class='date' date-start='$Bdate' date-end='$Ldate'></span></td></tr>"}?>
```

jquery code

```
 function get(){
     var id = $(this).attr("id");
     console.log(id);
     }
```

i want to get the id of this  after table load . but it is not working. plz tell me what i have done wrong

Comment: There's no `load` event for a `td`. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to get the id of this <td> after the table loads

Comment: What do you want to do with the id?

Comment: i actualy want this id  to get the price against this id and calculate profit

Comment: You need to parse through all td  elements to get their id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `load` event for a `td` element. You could loop the list of `td` elements and display their id like this if you want:

```js
$('table td').each(function (index, element) {
    console.log($(element).attr('id'));
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f1kt2r48/

### Update

You can target elements with the `id` attribute like this:

```js
$('table td[id]').each(function (index, element) {
    console.log($(element).attr('id'));
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/j1vf5wgc/

Comment: it is working . but as i am passing 3 columns. but only this one has id. how can i get this specific id in a variable?

Comment: @user Have a look at my update. You just have to target the `td` with an `id` attribute with `td[id]`.

Answer (score 1):

Take this out of your `<td>`

```
onload="get()"
```

Then, in your jQuery use this:

```
jQuery( function ( $ ) {
  $( "table tr" ).each( function () {
      console.log(this.next("td").attr('id'));
  } )
});
```

Note:  Untested code but should work

**EDIT:**

```
jQuery( function ( $ ) {
  var ids = [];
  $( "table tr" ).each( function () {
      ids += this.next("td").attr('id');
  } );

  console.log(ids);
});
```

Comment: it is working . but as i am passing 3 columns. but only this one has id. how can i get this specific id in a variable?